# In RNN Back Propagation through time, why is the D(h_t)/D(h_(t-1)) diagonal?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, backpropagation

I was going through backpropagation in time for RNN, in the deep learning book of Joshua Bengio et.al. (deep learning book , section 10.2.1 ).

Given a network as:

[image]

the book tells that the backpropagation of the error gradient respect with the state h(t) is given by:

[image]

So, why is the matrix of the D(h_(t+1))/D(h_t) diagonal? How is its solution obtained?

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide a sketch of the derivation. Omitting the bias term (since anyways we take derivatives later), the recursion looks like:
$$\mathbf{h_{t+1}}=tanh(\mathbf{ U x_{t}+W h_{t}}) $$ where the $tanh$ is taken elementwise.

Now, since $\mathbf{h_{t}}$ and $\mathbf{h_{t+1}}$ are vectors, the derivative $\frac{\partial \mathbf{h_{t+1}}}{\partial \mathbf{h_{t}}}$ is a  [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

1. Notice that if $y=tanh(x), dy/dx=1-tanh^2(x)=1-y^2$.
2. Let's see how a single element of the Jacobian looks like. Assume that the hidden layers are of dimension $n$ Now $h_{t+1, i}=tanh(\sum_{k=1} ^{n} w_{ik}h_{t,k}+ g(x))$. Here $g(x)$ stands for some function of x.
3. Hence $\frac{\partial h_{t+1, i}}{\partial h_{t, j}}$ = $1-h_{t+1,i}^{2}w_{i,j}$. This corresponds to element in position $(i,j)$ of the Jacobian (from #1 above).
4. This multiplier $1-h_{t+1,i}^{2}$ applies to each element of the $i^{th}$ row of the Jacobian.
5. From basic linear algebra you can show that pre-multiplying a matrix $A$ by a diagonal matrix $diag(b_{i,i})$ is equivalent to scaling up row $i$ of matrix $A$ by $b_{i,i}$

**Hence the term $diag(1-\mathbf{h_{t+1}^{2}})$ occurs as a premultiplier to the matrix $\mathbf{W}$**

Comment: Could you please share how the derivation is performed? I can not understand form where come term W(i, j) ? if dy/dx=1-y^2 it needs to be just 1-h^2(t+1, i)
I do not understand how the W(i,j) appears at the point 3.

Comment: I think $\frac{\partial h_{t+1, i}}{\partial h_{t, j}}$ = $1-h_{t,i}^{2}w_{i,j}$